# Mouse position of dynamic elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking around this for a while now with no real answer out there, my scenario:

```
$(document).on('click', '.slide-1', function (e) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var left = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var top = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            console.log(left);
            console.log(top);
        });
```

I've tried all sorts, `offsetLeft`, `offsetTop`, using the `offet()` object in jQuery... all seem to be relative towards the document when using `$(document).on` (which I need to as .slide-1 is dynamic).

The problem is that when the window is resized, the values are always different and I can't pinpoint a singular mouse click position. Has anyone done this before and can give me any pointers?

Comment: What values do you want in `left` and `top`? The distance from the point of click to `.slide-1`? Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net and tell us the output you get and expect?

Comment: It'll be the relative position of the mouse click on slide-1, which is an image.

Comment: works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/u5h6F/

Comment: It's hard to properly replicate on jsFiddle. When you resize the browser window (different sized viewpoint) those values change. I want a unified value, no matter what the window size?

Comment: @ChrisDixon, I get the same value no matter what browser window size; it's always relative to the top left of the div. (Tried on my own fiddle, and on @roasted's.)